# Printing Tree and skipping certain values

Tags: c#, recursion, printing, tree

here i have the following code and input that prints a tree structure. My question is how can i make it so that the nodes and leafs that have the value "Unavailable" are skipped from being printed.

```
namespace Tree{public class TreeNode<T>

{
    private T value;

    private bool hasParent;

    private List<TreeNode<T>> children;


    public TreeNode(T value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Cannot insert null value");
        }

        this.value = value;
        this.children = new List<TreeNode<T>>();
    }
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.value;
        }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public int ChildrenCount
    {
        get
        {
            return this.children.Count;
        }
    }
    public void AddChild(TreeNode<T> child)
    {
        if (child == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Cannot insert null value");
        }
        if (child.hasParent)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The node already has a parent");
        }

        child.hasParent = true;
        this.children.Add(child);
    }
    public TreeNode<T> GetChild(int index)
    {
        return this.children[index];
    }
}

public class Tree<T>
{

    private TreeNode<T> root;
    public Tree(T value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Cannot insert null value");
        }

        this.root = new TreeNode<T>(value);
    }

    public Tree(T value, params Tree<T>[] children) : this(value)
    {
        foreach (Tree<T> child in children)
        {
            this.root.AddChild(child.root);
        }
    }

    public TreeNode<T> Root
    {
        get
        {
            return this.root;
        }
    }

    private void PrintDFS(TreeNode<T> root, string spaces)
    {
        if (this.root == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(spaces + root.Value);

        TreeNode<T> child = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < root.ChildrenCount; i++)
        {
            child = root.GetChild(i);
            PrintDFS(child, spaces + "   ");
        }
    }
    public void TraverseDFS()
    {
        this.PrintDFS(this.root, string.Empty);
    }
}

public static class TreeExample
{
    static void Main()
    {

        Tree<string> tree =
        new Tree<string>("John",
            new Tree<string>("Jasmine",
                new Tree<string>("Jay"),
                new Tree<string>("Unavailable")),
             new Tree<string>("Unavailable",
                new Tree<string>("Jack"),
                new Tree<string>("Jeremy")),
            new Tree<string>("Johanna")

            );
    tree.TraverseDFS();


    }
}}
```

right now it prints :(John, (Jasmine, (Jay), (Unavailable)), (Unavailable, (Jack, (Jeremy))), (Johanna))

I need it to print :(John, (Jasmine, (Jay)), (Johanna))

So basically skip every leaf with the value "Unavailable" and every node with the value "Unavailable" and all children from that node

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
private void PrintDFS(TreeNode<T> root, string spaces)
{
    if (this.root == null
        || "Unavailable" == root.Value.ToString())
    {
        return;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: when i typed your solution it says "operator'==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and string:

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is a literally correct answer to the question, but it bakes in logic about what to do with the tree into the tree itself. A tree is a kind of collection or data structure, and you don't often see a List or Dictionary that is able to print itself. Instead the collection provides the right methods to get or change its contents so that you can do what you want.

In your case, you could do something like the following:

```
public enum TreeVisitorResult {
    SkipNode,
    Continue
}

// the following two methods inside Tree<T>:

public void VisitNodes(Func<TreeNode<T>, int, TreeVisitorResult> visitor) {
    VisitNodes(0, this.root, visitor);
}

private void VisitNodes(int depth, TreeNode<T> node,
    Func<TreeNode<T>, int, TreeVisitorResult> visitor) {

    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }

    var shouldSkip = visitor(node, depth);
    if (shouldSkip == TreeVisitorResult.SkipNode) {
        return;
    }

    TreeNode<T> child = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildrenCount; i++) {
        child = node.GetChild(i);
        VisitNodes(depth + 1, child, visitor);
    }
}
```

If you had this method, you could write the Print method outside of the Tree classes, as:

```
tree.VisitNodes((treeNode, depth) => { // <- this lambda will be called for every node
    if (treeNode.Value == "Unavailable") { // <- no need to ToString or cast here, since
                                           // we know that T is string here
        return TreeVisitorResult.SkipNode;
    } else {
        var spaces = new string(' ', depth * 3);
        Console.WriteLine(spaces + treeNode.Value);     
    }
});
```